# Why does the DIV not expand to display text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/st8q8z5g/5/

Partial CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
}
b.title {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  clear: both;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
b.message {
  color: #EDEDED;
  clear: both;
  display:block;
}
```

I am running into two issues:

- Why does the text alert get cut off if the screen is less than 820px?
  (Would like the DIV to expand to show the alert automatically without
  setting a height)
- <del>When pressing the "Pause" button the "Play" button is displayed but
  it loses the CSS for the WIDTH and MARGIN. (The "Play" button does
  not stretch and does not have the margin like the "Pause" button)</del> **[FIXED]**

How can I fix the above issues.

Comment: If you open the fiddle and make the result screen smaller, you can see. I will post a screenshot if it is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is you have a `overflow:hidden` in your html, you might want to remove that and also you might want to keep a `position:relative` on the  msgAlert divs

Comment: @dvenkatsagar If I remove `position: absolute` the message jumps as it fades out and then in... https://jsfiddle.net/st8q8z5g/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do a workaround where you can manually set the height of the blue container divs.

You can change the html like this:

HTML

```
<div class="blue-container" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 98%; padding: 1%; background: #0070C6;">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; clear: both; text-align: left; position: absolute; right: 2%; top: 8%; z-index: 9999999; color: #FFF;">
        <span id="msgCurr">1</span>/<span id="msgOf"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="light-blue-container" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; background: #009DF5;">
        <div class="section group brClear">
            <div class="col span_short vertAlignT span_pad_all">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="transparent" id="prevAlert">Previous</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="transparent" id="playAlert">Play</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="transparent" id="pauseAlert">Pause</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="transparent" id="nextAlert">Next</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col span_long vertAlignT span_pad_all alertHolder">
                <div class="msgAlert">
                    <b class="title">The title alert goes here #1</b>
                    <b class="message">The alert message will go here 1...</b>
                </div>
                <div class="msgAlert">
                    <b class="title">The title alert goes here #2</b>
                    <b class="message">The alert message will go here 2...</b>
                </div>
                <div class="msgAlert">
                    <b class="title">The title alert goes here #3</b>
                    <b class="message">The alert message will go here 3...</b>
                </div>
                <div class="msgAlert">
                    <b class="title">The title alert goes here #4</b>
                    <b class="message">The alert message will go here 4...</b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the css, what you can do is, using a media query, keep it like this:

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {

    .light-blue-container{
      height:100%
    }

    .blue-container{
      height:21em
    }

...
```

Here is fiddle:

JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/st8q8z5g/9/

As you are keeping the msgAlert div position to absolute, it fixes the fade problems, but when you change the screen size, it would need to act as if its position is relative but should also have the fade smoothness, which i think might be difficult to achieve. So instead of that, just change the containers height and set it manually when the screen size is less than 820px. But if you are unwilling to compromise the dynamic height, you can achieve it using jquery or javascript. But I think for now this should solve your problem.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle, so I can test? Thanks.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/st8q8z5g/8 - Keep everything as is as far as functionality, just the ability for the text to display when less than 820px? Thanks.

Comment: I re-answered the question, hope it helps. But if you do not want to set a height, and you want keep the msgAlert position to absolute, I suggest you change the animation logic in the javascript in such a way that, if would first fadeout totally and hide it and then fade In again after that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/st8q8z5g/14/ I am trying to set the height of the DIV based on the height of the content but it's not working. Any idea? Fixed it here: https://jsfiddle.net/st8q8z5g/15/ :)

Comment: I was actually about give that solution, but something was missing, Anyway good it was solved.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it helped me solve the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

> *Why does the text alert get cut off if the screen is less than 820px? (Would like the DIV to expand to show the alert automatically without setting a height)*

The `.msgAlert` has `position: absolute` and the absolutely positioned elements do not take any height in the viewport. Removing `position: absolute` from there works:

```
.msgAlert {
  /* position: absolute; */
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

> *When pressing the "Pause" button the "Play" button is displayed but it loses the CSS for the WIDTH and MARGIN. (The "Play" button does not stretch and does not have the margin like the "Pause" button)*

The `#playAlert` has `display: inline` set very hard, even though if you change, it doesn't. It has to be `block`.

You can fix it using:

```
$('#playAlert').css("display", "block").hide();
```

> *If I remove `position: absolute` the message jumps as it fades out and then in...*

Give a `min-height` for the container so that it doesn't jump. `:)`

> The "Play" button isn't the same width if I use your fiddle `:/`

I left this for you to figure out **intentionally**. But you made to answer this. Here's the solution:

```
$('#playAlert').css("display", "inline-block").hide();
```

**Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e34pzhu3/**

Comment: The only issue with not using `position: absolute;` is when the content fades out and then in, it jumps and not a smooth transition. Example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/st8q8z5g/6/

Comment: Checking it out now. Thank you :)

Comment: @SiKni8 Awesome. This should work. I checked in mine and it is good.

Comment: @SiKni8 See the udpated answer for your question.

Comment: @SiKni8 *If I remove `position: absolute` the message jumps as it fades out and then in...*

Give a `min-height` for the container so that it doesn't jump. `:)`

Comment: The "Play" button isn't the same width if I use your fiddle :/

Comment: @SiKni8 I saw that. Intentionally left to you to fix it. If not, I can add that too. `:(` Then there's no effort you will put. `:(`

Comment: I can only fix it if I use `inline-block` I did put effort in creating it, which should count :)

Comment: @SiKni8 Great. I will. Check updated answer. I am leaving for the bus now.

Comment: As you can see, the next DIV fades in below the current DIV and then moves (only less than 820px) up which isn't what I am looking for. With absolute positioning, the transition is smooth. Thanks any way.

Comment: The text still jumps when even though min-height is given.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/st8q8z5g/8/ - Keep everything as is as far as functionality, just the ability for the text to display when less than 820px? Thanks.

Comment: @SiKni8 I don't understand. What is happening now?